# Filtrar en Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, searchview

Quiero filtrar mi lista por el nombre del titulo ya que cuando busco el titulo del item de mi lista tiene que ser con el nombre exacto. Este es mi ListView, al momento de buscar el titulo de algun item este no lo busca como quiero. Si hay alguna manera de filtrar por aproximacion del titulo seria de gran ayuda.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/detailsCG.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/model/cantoscglist.dart';

class ListScreenCG extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title:
              Text('Cantos Corario Grande', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showSearch(context: context, delegate: LetraCGSearch());
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: cantosListCG.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              LetraCG letraCG = cantosListCG[index];
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(letraCG.titleCG),
                  //subtitle: Text(letra.numero.toString()),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => DetailsCG(letraCG)));
                  },
                ),
              );
            }));
  }
}

class LetraCGSearch extends SearchDelegate<LetraCG> {
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = "";
        },
      )
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.navigate_before),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },

      /*onPressed: () {
        //close(context, null);
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),*/
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(query);
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final mylist = query.isEmpty
        ? cantosListCG
        : cantosListCG
            .where((element) =>
                element.titleCG.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase()))
            .toList();
    ;
    return mylist.isEmpty
        ? Center(
            child: Text(
            'Not Results Found...',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ))
        : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: mylist.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final LetraCG letracg = mylist[index];
              return ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => DetailsCG(letracg)));
                },
                title: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(letracg.titleCG),
                    //Text(listitem.letraCG),
                    Divider()
                  ],
                ),
              );
            });
  }
}
```

Aqui es donde tengo mi lista con los items y la informacion que deseo filtrar. Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de poder filtrarlo no por el nombre exacto del titulo.

```
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LetraCG {
 int numeroCG;
 String titleCG;
 String letraCG;

 LetraCG({
   required this.numeroCG,
   required this.titleCG,
   required this.letraCG,
 });
}

List<String> cantoslistOnSearch = [];

List<LetraCG> cantosListCG = [
 LetraCG(numeroCG: 1, titleCG: 'No nos rendiremos', letraCG: '''Letra'''),
 LetraCG(numeroCG: 2, titleCG: '2.- Escondido', letraCG: '''Letra'''),
 LetraCG(numeroCG: 4, titleCG: '4.- Humilde', letraCG: '''Letra'''),
 LetraCG(numeroCG: 5, titleCG: 'Tacos', letraCG: ''' Letra '''),
];
```

Muchas gracias por su atencion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En lugar de `startsWith` podrías usar `contains` :

```dart
element.titleCG.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/contains.html

Comment: Mucchas gracias! Fue de gran ayuda!